# AngularJS to replace textbox value with expression with a function call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular form where ng-repeat is used to create several TDs and each TD element holds a textbox whose value I want to modify using a function call with parameter. I hold values in an array and want to pick a value from there and put in textbox element.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="myObject in arrayOfObjects">
                <input type="text" ng-???="{{ myFunctonCall(myObject.Property) }}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a standard ng directive or it can be achieved using formatters, parsers?

Comment: `ng-model` is used therefore. But you can't use a function there, and bind your input directly to your object.

Comment: So textboxes are not editable?

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe but this will bring me two way binding. Also my form is dynamic, it constantly changes the amount of controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to initialize a scope value inside each child scope of ng-repeat. Those values won't be shared with your parent controller, where arrayOfObjects is defined.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit 
(as said in the doc, do not use too much ngInit)

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="object in arrayOfObjects">
                <input type="text" 
                       ng-init="value = myFunctionCall(object.Property);" 
                       ng-model="value" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as @Deblaton Jean-Philippe said you can use `ng-model` to read the data

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myinitialvalue" />
```

then process it in the controller the way you want:

```
$scope.$watch('myinitialvalue' function(newval, oldval){
  //newval is equal to value of myinitialvalue
  //here we modify it and assign to myvar, here for example we just add 'abc' to it
  $scope.myvar = newval + 'abc';
});
```

and angular template syntax {{myvar}} to show it in textarea or in some other place if the page:

```
<textarea>{{myvar}}</textarea>
```

Comment: But won't ng-model add two-binding which is useless and even harmful in this situation?

Comment: he can add static binding syntax {{::value}. anyhow question details seemed a bit convoluted to me, I just wanted to describe the generic approach

Comment: You can disable a textbox if you don't want it to be editable.

Comment: @shershen, could you tell me what needs to be more specific in question, or it is not clear what has to be achieved?

Comment: @Deblaton Jean-Philippe, i want it to be editable, but i need only to set the value and have no binding with any of $scope variables

Comment: 'binding' - IS setting a value actually. "have no binding with any of $scope variables" why this ? $scope in Angular IS uses as way to pass data from controller to template and back! so any way you achieve this will be though scope somehow